# Re-sign xcarchive file

Tags: ios, code-signing

A client wants to re-sign the IPA file with their own certificate and since that's pretty easy using [this](https://github.com/MarcusSmith/ipaHelper/tree/master), what I actually need is to re-sign the entire xcarchive so the dSYM's UUID matches the IPA's UUID. Otherwise crash symbolication won't work.
Is it possible to re-sign a xcarchive file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files in the archive are **not** signed! And the UUID doesn't change when signing either. The IPA is also not in the archive, but created from the application bundle in the archive.

So simply provide the complete archive to your client, and they can copy it into the archives folder in Xcode and use the build in tools to sign and export the archive in the Xcode organizer.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Xcode 9+, the title of the question is essentially how to re-sign an xarchive file, please note that xarchive is a higher level where ipa file is embedded, the way to deal with this file is to extract them "show packages" then you'll see the actual app on "products/applications/name.app" then, copy the name.app (asssuming this is your app) to another folder, re-sign them using this [method](http://dev.mlsdigital.net/posts/how-to-resign-an-ios-app-from-external-developers/) , the article is old but works on xcode 9.

Once you've re-signed it you can put it back on the extracted xarchive file earlier, then if you double click it will open on xcode archive and now you can distribute them under your signature.

Also if you run into problems with provisions, just make sure that push notification is enabled /disabled on the app, then change your entitlements.plist. Hope this helps anyone still looking for this kind of issue.

Comment: The link http://dev.mlsdigital.net/posts/how-to-resign-an-ios-app-from-external-developers/ is unfortunately not working.